# Como procesar texto formato HTML en una grilla

Tags: string, delphi, grid

estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde tengo informacion en formato HTML porque luego se lleva a la web. El tema es que en la aplicacion necesito visualizar dicha informacion en formato de grilla, pero no encuentro una manera eficiente de lograr que ese texto HTML sea procesado en la grilla. (Es decir, que no se vean los tags y eso).
Estuve indagando y probe con el componente DevExpress, sin embargo este componente no tiene ninguna grilla que acepte textos en formato HTML. De momento lo que hago es convertirlo a RTF en tiempo de ejecucion para que la grilla pueda mostrar el texto. Esto es tedioso y pesado para el sistema ya que suele tratarse de una cantidad de registros alta.

¿Como puedo procesar un texto HTML en una grilla?

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender a qué te refieres con _"en formato grilla"_, pues no me queda claro si la información está en un DataSet que luego asocias a alguna grilla en particular o si el HTML tiene grillas, o qué exactamente es lo que buscas. 

Si el HTML es simple, la idea de convertir el texto a RTF no me parece descabellada, ni tediosa. Cuando dices que es pesado para el sistema, pienso que quizás no se está haciendo en el momento o de la manera que sería óptima, pero es difícil dar alguna recomendación sin conocer más detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final no hay secretos.
Si en Base de Datos tienes un campo que almacena texto en `HTML` y quieres mostrarlo en un `DBGrid` estandard, hay que realizar 2 tareas.

1. Pintar el contenido de la celda con el `HTML`
2. Previamente a eso habrás tenido que convertir el contenido del campo.

El `Grid` de las `DevExpress` como comentas permite mostrar `RTF`, por lo tanto has tenido que realizar un paso previo de HTML->RTF. Puedes buscar algún otro componente que lo haga, pero no es fácil, por una razón:
*"Parsear"* y *"pintar"* `HTML` no es simple ni rápido, ya que el `HTML` es mucho más complejo (permite muchas más opciones) que el `RTF`, por ejemplo. Posiblemente por eso `DevExpress` no lo implementa y muchos otros componentes tampoco.

Además no creo que sea una opión "correcta" desde el punto de vista de diseño, ya que eso va a hacer que el `GRID` se vuelva lento y farragoso, más cuanto mayor sea el número de registros a mostrar.

Tal vez deberías plantearte si esa opción es verdaderamente necesaria.

**VARIANTE**:
Una posible variante es "simplificar" las opciones que quieres pintar dentro del amplio abanico de posibilidades del `HTML` y te centras en lo que podría ser un Label (un texto) de forma que te quedarías con los atributos básicos del `HTML`.

Es este caso, puedes encontrar componentes (devivabdos de un `TLabel`) que permiten convertir un texto en `HTML` (con tags) y mostrarlo en un Label de Delphi. Pero como comento, los atributos que se muestran en ese Label son deducios respecto a todo lo disponible en `HTML`. En estos casos se suele tener en cuenta *Tamaño*, propiedades de la fuente (*negrita*, *cursiva*, *subrayado*,...), cambio de *fuente*, *color de fondo* y *color de la letra*.

Si esto te es suficiente, puedes revisar alguno de estos componentes y ver cómo hacen la *conversión* y el *pintado*.:

- http://www.infintuary.org/stlabel.php
- https://github.com/digao-dalpiaz/DzHTMLText

Al final estos componentes "parsean" el `HTML` y a partr de ahí pintan en un `TCanvas` (en el caso de los derivados de un `TLabel`). Eso exactamente es lo que tú deberás hacer. Hacer la conversión y pintar en el `TCanvas` de la celda del `Grid` que quieres que muestre ese campo.